# Editing option for pdf is not showing in ios12 using QuickLook

Tags: swift, pdf

I am using QuickLook for opening and editing pdf in swift.  It is working fine in ios 14 but the editting option is not showing in ios 12. i am attaching the screen shot of my simulator. In this image the editing of is there but if i am running it in any ios12 device like iphone 5s it is not showing

```
//MARK:- QLPreviewControllerDataSource
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension AllPdfFilesViewController: QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        
        return self.previewItem as QLPreviewItem
    }
}

//MARK:- QLPreviewControllerDelegate

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension AllPdfFilesViewController: QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
    func previewController(
        _ controller: QLPreviewController,
        editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem
    ) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
        .createCopy
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was only introduced in iOS 13. so it won't work on 12.